# setw not found in MSVC 2013 or NetBeans

Tags: visual-c++, netbeans-7, setw

I'm trying to write some simple code to learn cout formatting, and both the IDEs listed in the title complain that they can't find/resolve the identifier setw(). Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main() {
    cout << setw(10) << "Hello";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! I forgot to `using std::setw;`.

Comment: You can make your answer as answering the question. Then everyone will know you resolved your problem.

Comment: I apparently can't mark it as answered for 2 more days. I'll try to remember, though.